# need to merge the array with matching the value

Tags: php, arrays

I have a array like this how  i will get new array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [model] => MX555
            [color] => RED
            [qty] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [model] => MX555
            [color] => RED
            [qty] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [model] => MX555
            [color] => Green
            [qty] => 2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [model] => MX555
            [color] => Green
            [qty] => 1
        )
)
```

I need to return the array like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [model] => MX555
            [color] => RED
            [qty] => 4
        )



    [1] => Array
        (
            [model] => MX555
            [color] => Green
            [qty] => 4
        )
)
```

Comment: And... what problem do you have with it?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? return a selected index? I'm sorry the question is not clear.

Comment: How i will create new array from this

Comment: For second index in array qty should 3 i guess ?

Comment: Yes qty will be 3 but how  i will create this array

Comment: check out my answer for the code snippet to achieve this solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to identify duplicate items by multiple values, in this case both `model` and `color` (if you only want to group by the single value `color` then see RamC's answer instead). One approach is to create an array, where each key is created by concatenating those values:

```
function mergeQuantitiesByModelAndColor(array $array)
{
    $merged_array = array();
    foreach ($array as $item) {
        $key = $item['model'] . '|' . $item['color'];
        if (!isset($merged_array[$key])) {
            $merged_array[$key] = $item;
        } else {
            $merged_array[$key]['qty'] += $item['qty'];
        }
    }
    return array_values($merged_array);
}
```

When tested as follows (php 5.6):

```
$array = array(
    array(
        'model' => 'MX555',
        'color' => 'RED',
        'qty' => 2,
    ),
    array(
        'model' => 'MX555',
        'color' => 'RED',
        'qty' => 2,
    ),
    array(
        'model' => 'MX555',
        'color' => 'Green',
        'qty' => 2,
    ),
    array(
        'model' => 'MX555',
        'color' => 'Green',
        'qty' => 1,
    ),
);

var_dump(mergeQuantitiesByModelAndColor($array));
```

Gives output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["model"]=>
    string(5) "MX555"
    ["color"]=>
    string(3) "RED"
    ["qty"]=>
    int(4)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["model"]=>
    string(5) "MX555"
    ["color"]=>
    string(5) "Green"
    ["qty"]=>
    int(3)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Sum Quantity grouping by element

From your question, it is inferable that you want to add the quantity of similar items.

If that is the case, then you can achieve it with the following code snippet.

In the below snippet, I've grouped the items using the element `color`.

Feel free to change it as per your requirement.

**Snippet**

```
$group_by = 'color';

foreach ($data as $item) {
    if (!isset($res[$item[$group_by]])) {
        $res[$item[$group_by]] =  $item;
    } else {
        $res[$item[$group_by]]['qty'] += $item['qty'];
    }
}
```

**Code**

```
$data = [
  [
      'model' => "MX555",
      'color' => "RED",
      'qty' => 2,
  ],
  [
      'model' => "MX555",
      'color' => "RED",
      'qty' => 2,
  ],
  [
      'model' => "MX555",
      'color' => "Green",
      'qty' => 2,
  ],
  [
      'model' => "MX555",
      'color' => "Green",
      'qty' => 1,
  ],
];

$res = [];
$group_by = 'color';

foreach ($data as $item) {
    if (!isset($res[$item[$group_by]])) {
        $res[$item[$group_by]] =  $item;
    } else {
        $res[$item[$group_by]]['qty'] += $item['qty'];
    }
}

print_r(array_values($res));
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [model] => MX555
            [color] => RED
            [qty] => 4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [model] => MX555
            [color] => Green
            [qty] => 3
        )

)
```